# Visibility between two writers

Tags: scala

When writing the writers for these two models I get an error.

Here are my models :

```
case class Ad (
    var id: Long,
    var account: Account,
    ...
    var pictures: List[Picture]) extends Model

object Ad {
    implicit val adWrites = Json.writes[Ad]
}

case class Picture(
    var id: Long,
    var ad: Ad) extends Model

object Picture {
    implicit pictureWrites = Json.writes[Picture]

    implicit def listPictureWrites[PictureScala](implicit fmt: Writes[PictureScala]): Writes[List[PictureScala]] = new Writes[List[PictureScala]] {
        def writes(ts: List[PictureScala]) = JsArray(ts.map(t => Json.toJson(t)(fmt)))
    }
}
```

This does not work. I got the following messages: On the pictureWrites (=> "No implicit Writes for models.AdScala available.") and on the adWrites (=> "No implicit Writes for java.util.List[models.PictureScala] available.").

I think this is because each writers needs the writes method of the other case class. But how can I solve this problem ? If I comment the "ad" and "pictures" var this works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Json.writes` macro isn't going to work in this case, since your types are recursive. Explicitly defining your `Writes` instances isn't too bad, though:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

// Next two lines for the sake of a complete working example.
trait Model
type Account = String

case class Ad (
  var id: Long,
  var account: Account,
  var pictures: List[Picture]
) extends Model

object Ad {
  implicit val adWrites: Writes[Ad] = (
    (__ \ 'id).write[Long] and
    (__ \ 'account).write[Account] and
    (__ \ 'pictures).write[List[Picture]]
  )(unlift(Ad.unapply))
}

case class Picture(var id: Long, var ad: Ad) extends Model

object Picture {
  implicit val pictureWrites: Writes[Picture] = (
    (__ \ 'id).write[Long] and
    (__ \ 'ad).lazyWrite(Ad.adWrites)
  )(unlift(Picture.unapply))
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val ad1 = Ad(1, "foo", Nil)
ad1: Ad = Ad(1,foo,List())

scala> val ad2 = Ad(2, "bar", List(Picture(1, ad1)))
ad2: Ad = Ad(2,bar,List(Picture(1,Ad(1,foo,List()))))

scala> Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(ad2))
res8: String = 
{
  "id" : 2,
  "account" : "bar",
  "pictures" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "ad" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "account" : "foo",
      "pictures" : [ ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

Note in particular the `lazyWrite` in `pictureWrites`, which is necessary because of the recursion.

Comment: Seems to be working without adding the first two lines.

Comment: Right—those two lines are for the sake of other people who don't have the full context of your code but may have run into a similar problem.